# Copying data from sheets to docs and generating a new document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm at that beginner-to-intermediate state in programming where I know enough to piece something together that can be rather complex but perhaps I don't go about it the best way, get stumped, and its definitely not optimized.

I've build an invoice generator that takes the data inputted from a sheet and translates it to the same template in google docs. I want to have a script which takes the quote information, and copies the lines over to the template in docs, unless the row is empty, in which case it skips to the next.

So far I've achieved this by specifying each cell as an independent variable, and copying them individually no matter if they are populated or not.

It works, but it does not seem like the most efficient solution and it becomes a pain rather quickly as we still have to fix some formatting in the generated quote document.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sinput = ss.getSheetByName("QUOTE TEMPLATE");

//TO GENERATE DOCUMENT
  var templateId = '1jIxHUZAoVd00a9eTZM-ORL0H7qMLfEmyat04l89GNwE';

  //devis
  var item1 = sinput.getRange("B18").getValues();
  var item2 = sinput.getRange("B19").getValues();
  var item3 = sinput.getRange("B20").getValues();

  var qty1 = sinput.getRange("C18").getValues();
  var qty2 = sinput.getRange("C19").getValues();
  var qty3 = sinput.getRange("C20").getValues();

  var unitprice1 = sinput.getRange("D18").getValues();
  var unitprice2 = sinput.getRange("D19").getValues();
  var unitprice3 = sinput.getRange("D20").getValues();

  var total1 = sinput.getRange("E18:G18").getValues();
  var total2 = sinput.getRange("E19:G19").getValues();  
  var total3 = sinput.getRange("E20:G20").getValues();


//Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();

//Get the document body as a variable
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

//All the text to be replaced

  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING1%', item1 );
  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING2%', item2 );
  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING3%', item3 );;

  body.replaceText('%Q1%', qty1 );
  body.replaceText('%Q2%', qty2 );
  body.replaceText('%Q3%', qty3 );

  body.replaceText('%PRIC1%',  unitprice1 );
  body.replaceText('%PRIC2%',  unitprice2 );
  body.replaceText('%PRIC3%',  unitprice3);;

  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_1%', total1 );
  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_2%',  total2);
  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_3%', total3 );;

}
```

This is a reduced version as the original code accounts for 20 different lines of input, maybe more.
Currently any empty cells result in a comma (,) being exported into the google document.

I would love to :

1. reduce the code length
2. make the code faster
3. construct the code to skip empty lines
4. use something that is not `body.replaceText`

but I can't figure out how to properly express the "if a line is empty simply move to the next bit" in code.

I've got about 6 months of experience behind me so i consider myself still very much a learner. Any help or insight is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO and double welcome to your refreshing attitude about polishing up your code.

Comment: Hello, and thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fn(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var data = ss.getRange("B18:G20").getValues();

//Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId(); 
//Get the document body as a variable
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

//All the text to be replaced
  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING1%', data[0][0]);
  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING2%', data[1][0]);
  body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING3%', data[2][0]);

  body.replaceText('%Q1%', data[0][1]);
  body.replaceText('%Q2%', data[1][1]);
  body.replaceText('%Q3%', data[2][1]);

  body.replaceText('%PRIC1%',  data[0][2] );
  body.replaceText('%PRIC2%',  data[1][2]);
  body.replaceText('%PRIC3%',  data[2][2]);

  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_1%', data[0][3] + " " + data[0][4] + " " + data[0][5]);
  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_2%', data[1][3] + " " + data[1][4] + " "  + data[1][5]);
  body.replaceText('%TOTAL_3%', data[2][3] + " " + data[2][4] + " " + data[2][5]);
}
```

I assumed that for the totals you wanted a sum of the values in those cells, if this is not the case, please let me know and I'll update my code.

As for what you did, according to the [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), you should avoid multiple calls to the APIs, since they are the heaviest methods you'd be using (the `getValue()` in particular in your case).  The ideal thing is to get values once using `getValues()` and work on the 2D array that is returned ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)))

Another thing, when you called `body.replaceText('%DESCRIPTION_STRING1%', item1 )`, `item1`, `item2` & `item3` were all 2D arrays, so using them in replace would not have worked, which is why I asked what you want to do with them.

Lastly, I think an alternative to `body.replaceText()` would be to extract the body's text and do all the searches on that string and then replacing the entire body with the result. This would mean less calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I updated the code to update the totals as a string

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for this! As for your questions - the totals are not sums, these are already values that should simply be copied one next to another for admin's purposes. What I'm trying to do is take the values from sheets and copy them across to a pre-populated template that we have in docs that we then use to invoice clients. The script has another part that, when triggered, takes the populated values and copies them to another tab for our producers to track the project. Hence me wanting to attempt a loop and only copy the populated lines as opposed to everything...